# Why is Vue .splice() always removing the last item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**Update:** It's working now.  I'm not sure what I did - honestly I don't recall changing anything, but I'm sure it was due to the feedback - so thanks to everyone who helped.

I have a loop that generates table rows based on objects in an array.  Whenever I trigger removal, regardless of the row I want to remove, it's always the last item in the array that gets removed.

**Data - stored as "meetingPlans"**

```
[
  {
    dow:"-T-R---",
    endTime:"11:45:00",
    startTime:"08:45:00"
  },
  {
    dow:"--W----",
    endTime:"12:45:00",
    startTime:"10:45:00"
  },
  {
    dow:"----F--",
    endTime:"15:00:00",
    startTime:"14:00:00"
  }
]
```

**Template**

```
<tr v-for="(meetingPlan,meetingPlanIndex) in meetingPlans" :key="meetingPlanIndex">
    <td>
      -- stuff here doesn't matter --
    </td>
    <td>
        -- stuff here doesn't matter either --
    </td>
    <td class = "pl-0">
        <button v-on:click="removeMeetingPlan(meetingPlanIndex)" type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <i class = "fas fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Vue code**

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el:"#dynamic-planning-column",
        delimiters:["<%","%>"],
        // This is defined server-side.  "meetingPlans" is one of the properties of planData
        data:window.planData,
        methods:{
            addReserveGroup:function(index){
                this.reserveGroups.push({number:'',description:'',cap:''});
            },
            removeReserveGroup:function(index){
                this.reserveGroups.splice(index,1);
            },
            addMeetingPlan:function(index){
                this.meetingPlans.push({id:0,dow:'',startTime:'',endTime:'',timeslot:-1});
            },
            removeMeetingPlan:function(index){
                this.meetingPlans.splice(index,1);
            },
            meetingPlanDowIsOdd:function(MeetingPlan){
                return MeetingPlan.dow.includes('M') || MeetingPlan.dow.includes('W') || MeetingPlan.dow.includes('F');
            }
        }
    });
```

To me, that looks like it should work.

**Debugging I've tried**

- Ensuring `meetingPlanIndex` in the template is a unique value.
- When I modify `removeMeetingPlan()` to output `index` and output `this.meetingPlans[index]` both are expected values.
- When I modify `removeMeetingPlan()` to be hardcoded: `this.meetingPlans.splice(0,1)` - it still removes the last item

**Solutions I've tried**
I read that one could make the `:key` the object rather than the number, so I modified the template to be:

```
<tr v-for="(meetingPlan,meetingPlanIndex) in meetingPlans" :key="meetingPlan">
```

That worked for the purposes of removing the correct row, but Vue threw warnings about duplicate keys, and using non-primitives as keys.

---

What else can I try?

Comment: When you say *'it's always the last item in the array that gets removed'*, how are you determining that? It sounds like you are modifying the array successfully but then the updated array is not being rendered correctly due to inappropriate use of `key`.

Comment: I'm not really able to reproduce this problem, but yeah, stringifying the object shouldn't fail.

Comment: change `:key="meetingPlanIndex"` to `:key="JSON.stringify(meetingPlan)"` probably

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Make that an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @skirtle I'm determining in 2 ways: (1) Using the Vue devtools extension I examine Root and see the data change (2) Looking at the UI I see the last element disappear.

Comment: @Quasipickle It sounds like you have stateful components inside your `<td>` elements but you haven't posted them so it's difficult to tell. I suspect if you tried having `<td>{{ meetingPlan }}</td>` (for debugging purposes) you'd find that it worked fine even without any `key` magic. If you've got functionality to edit the data in a row then you may find that `JSON.stringify` introduces a whole load of new problems. If the objects' properties don't change it should work nicely.

Comment: "When I modify removeMeetingPlan() to be hardcoded: his.meetingPlans.splice(0,1) - it still removes the last item" in combination with the invalid definition of `meetingPlans` above (each field is not comma separated) makes me think there's something abnormal about your array.

Comment: @skirtle I don't have any components here.  Basically I'm just wanting to use Vue to provide a simple way to add/remove table rows

Comment: @dispake The missing commas was just due to the fact I typed in the data here (it's not easily exportable from my system)  That was just a typing error - but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Where is `meetingPlans` declared? Can you paste your `data` function?

Comment: @RossAllen I've updated the post to show all my Vue code instead of just the specific method.

Comment: @Quasipickle Could you clarify what is actually in the `<td>` elements? I know you think it doesn't matter but it may be more important than it appears. You mentioned that: *'Looking at the UI I see the last element disappear.'*. But it still isn't clear how you are determining that it is the last element that is disappearing. You're right, it is the last element, but how can you tell? With the code you've currently posted all the rows look the same, so you wouldn't know which one has been removed.

Comment: @skirtle  The "Doesn't matter" sections generate a couple different `<select>s`.  They look different, which is how I can tell the UI is updated.  Try as I may to create as reduced a case as possible, I often end up removing something others may find relevant - sorry about that.  Also, I've updated the post because the code is working now.  I'm not sure what I changed, but I nonetheless appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Comment: @Quasipickle Please include the code for the contents of the `<td>` elements. Increasingly I think they're pivotal to the whole thing. As for your difficulties creating a suitable test case, my advice would be to use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) wherever possible. A complete, running example makes it much easier for everyone to reproduce the problem without having to speculate about the missing pieces.

Comment: @skirtle.  I see your point, but even when I completely deleted that output, I was still having the same problem - which I could verify using the devtools.  Please also note that the problem is solved - or rather, went away.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make an example with the code you provided - seems to work fine.

```js
Vue.component('meeting-plans', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      meetingPlans: [
        {
          dow: "-T-R---",
          endTime: "11:45:00",
          startTime: "08:45:00",
        },
        {
          dow: "--W----",
          endTime: "12:45:00",
          startTime: "10:45:00",
        },
        {
          dow: "----F--",
          endTime: "15:00:00",
          startTime: "14:00:00",
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeMeetingPlan: function(index) {
      this.meetingPlans.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr v-for="(meetingPlan,meetingPlanIndex) in meetingPlans" :key="meetingPlanIndex">
        <td class="pl-0">
          <button v-on:click="removeMeetingPlan(meetingPlanIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            Remove {{ meetingPlan.dow }}
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
})
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <meeting-plans />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: D'oh!  Right.  The missing commas were just due to my mistake transcribing.  Fixed.

Comment: The only differences I can readily see is that (1)you've created a component while I'm just using a raw app (ie: var vm = new Vue({...})).  Also, your data is a function while mine's just an object - but I think that's due to the component/app difference.  Should that have any appreciable effect?

Comment: (1) I don't think that should make a difference.  (2) Might be the problem. Data must be a function. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function